# I/flutter (29896): [firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I/flutter (29896): [firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel.

while im trying to connect flutter app with firebase authentification i got error like this

can you suggest any solution?

```
 Future signUp({required String email,required String password})async{
    try{
      return await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

    }catch(e){
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

this is my firebase connecting function.i want to connect with firebase authentification

Comment: did you solved ?